# How to find action ids of menu items in odoo?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, openerp-7

I just want to customize Accounting module so I wanna adopt some menus from there. So how can I find action ids for that particular menu item?
what is the easiest way?

Comment: Please be more clear with your stuff so I can help you better. Which menu action you want and why you need it ? you need external id of menu item to set parent menu ?

Comment: Please do follow the below link, i posted a new question .. Please help me out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33448098/customizing-accounting-and-finance-module-in-odoo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Example Code for menu id  get:

```
self.menu_xml_id = 'base.menu_action_res_users'

module_name, menu_xml_id = self.menu_xml_id.split('.')

dummy, menu_id = self.registry('ir.model.data').get_object_reference(self.cr, self.uid, module_name, menu_xml_id)

ir_ui_menu = self.registry('ir.ui.menu').browse(self.cr, self.uid, menu_id, context=None)

print "action_id==============", ir_ui_menu.action
```

## Odoo 11, 12, 13, 14

menu = self.env.ref('base.menu_action_res_users')

Comment: Should i put this code into parent logic file or what??

Comment: This is the logic of find action ids if you required then put it but that is hard code for accounting module in parent view if you customize then put this code in your customize code.

Comment: bro, i have created one module like accounting but only i created menus but didn't give any parent action ids.. thats why i am not getting your answer i hope it will work but how can i made it beneficial?? for me

Comment: This seems to be outdated. Does anyone have a working solution for Odoo 12?

Comment: `menu = self.env.ref('base.menu_action_res_users')` works for me.

Comment: Works, thanks. With ```self.env.ref('base.menu_action_res_users').id``` you can get the id

Answer (score 0):

Here required are stored in `params` as dict

```py
@api.model
def fields_view_get(self, view_id=None, view_type='form', toolbar=False, submenu=False):
    # {'action': 88, 'cids': 1, 'id': 38, 'menu_id': 69, 'model': 'hospital.appointment', 'view_type': 'form'}
    res = super(hospital_appointment, self).fields_view_get(view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type, toolbar=toolbar,submenu=submenu)
    params = self._context.get('params')
    print('\n\n\n',params)

    return res
```